# Flight times change so I effectively lose an entire day of my holidays

Tags: air-travel, germany, serbia

I booked a flight from Frankfurt to Belgrade with AirSerbia in February. A few weeks after this was moved from 9.50 in the morning (JU331) to 19.35 in the afternoon (JU334). This makes me lose an entire day of my holiday (4 days reduced to 3 days).

It also doesn't make sense to pay the hotel just for arriving late at night.

The airline notified me 14 days ahead of departure but I feel they still caused financial damage to me. I called and emailed them but they don't want to offer me an earlier flight.
They claim that they have none and can't book me on another airlines flight.

In general the customer service of AirSerbia is absolutely horrible and just wants to get me out of the phone line as fast as possible.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: I don't understand your remark about hotel not making sense. Hotels are paid per night and there doesn't seem to be any change in the number of nights you will be spending there. Hotels don't give discounts to people for checking in at midnight. You still need a place to sleep, don't you?

Comment: thats true, but it is not worth it to arrive so late, it would be preferable to arrive in the morning after to save that money:

I don't get anything out of arriving so late, except for paying an additional night

Comment: Do you have travel insurance? Is your hotel refundable? When did they notify you? What are the dates of travel? Can you change dates? It looks like the only non-stop flight FRA-BEG in the morning is Lufthansa's (11:20-13:10), but it doesn't fly every day, and LH's BEG-FRA flights are rather early, so your best option is probably LH one way and Air Serbia the other if you want to maximise your time there, but it's probably going to be a bit more expensive than having both flights on the same airline.

Comment: "I don't get anything out of arriving so late, except for paying an additional night" ... except that you can set your alarm the next morning at 6am, or 7am and start your day early. As it was, you are complaining about losing an entire day, while I think that having a flight that was leaving at 9:50, meaning you would arrive at about 10:30, then take a taxi/bus/shuttle to your hotel, etc. You weren't going to "start your vacation" until mid-afternoon anyway. So now spend most of the first day of your vacation, at home, doing stuff you would not have had time to do anyway....

Comment: That gives me at best 2 hours additonal on the next day. The taxi ride from the airport ist 20min. And dropping my luggage should not take more than 10min.

So I am loosing at least 8 hours. That is a huge percentage of my holiday. I also don't understand why you are defending such shitty behaviour. I would not have complained if I had arrived 2 or 3 hours later. But advertising a flight in the morning and then putting me on one in the afternoon is a borderline scam (bait and switch).

Answer (score 12):

> Is there anything I can do?

You can cancel for a full refund. Since they notified you 14 days before departure, you are not entitled to any further compensation.

https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm#cancellation

Take a look at current prices and arrival times for your travel dates. It looks like round trips in early August can be had for under $200, so maybe there is a better option for your needs.